# Saving colors using NSCoder?

Tags: colors, nscoder

How do you save (by which I mean encode and decode) colors such as ccc3, ccc4, etc using NSCoder?

It doesn't seem to be supported.  The only way I've been able to solve it is to save ints, and then when I need the colors I generate them from the ints.

Is there a formal way to save ccc3, ccc4 colors using NSCoder?

ie, I want to save;

```
ccColor4B topColor;
ccColor4B bottomColor;
```

But there does not seem to be a way to encode them or decode them with NSCoder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter now, I will continue to encode/decode ints and then deal with the colors in my code.